# jquery: onclick change background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following UL - LI html.

```
<UL>
<LI><span id='select1'>Text</span></LI>
<LI><span id='select2'>Text</span></LI>
<LI><span id='select3'>Text</span></LI>
<LI><span id='select4'>Text</span></LI>
<LI><span id='select5'>Text</span></LI>
<LI><span id='select6'>Text</span></LI>
</UL>
```

If I click on specific `<span>`, its background color should be changed. i.e. if I click on span having `id='select3'`, its background-color should be changed.

How this can be done using jQuery?

Comment: Attach a click handler to the spans in which you change the background color. What exactly do you need to know? What have you tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one :

```
$('li span[id^="select"]').click(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color',"#ccc")
})
```

what it does is, clicking the `span` inside `li` having id starting with 'select' changes the backgound color.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
jQuery("#select1").click(function(){jQuery(this).css({'background-color':'red})});
```

Hope it helps.

Update my answer to put handler on each select. You can add some attr to your span elements to represent color. e.g. `<span rel="red">Text</span>`.
And then you can write handler like

```
jQuery("ul span[id^='select']").click(function(){jQuery(this).css({'background-color':jQuery(this).attr('rel')})});
```

Comment: This will only add the click handler to the first element. Converting this to apply to multiple elements should be easy but you should mention it.

Comment: yes, here the #no of <LI>s will be dynamic. then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("span").click(function(){
  if($(this).attr('id') == "select3") $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: theres probably a way to combine the if statement into the selector, but i don't do much jQuery

Comment: Not only there are no select elements, but : should , in the css method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many list elements, you may want to use event delegation and only manage a click on the `ul`. So you can do

```
$('ul').click(function(event) {
    switch($(event.target).attr('id')) {
        case select1:
            $(event.target).css('background-color', 'red');
            break;
        //More case statements
    }
});
```